# subset data with confidence interval in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, confidence-interval

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID Value Ratio
P1 W 0.512
P1 X 0.444
P1 Y 0.342
P1 Z 0.617
...
P2 W 0.400
P2 X 0.333
P2 Y 0.200
P2 Z 0.500
...
P3 W 0.250
P3 X 0.500
P3 Y 0.667
P3 Z 0.750
...
```

First, I want ggplot to only plot the values of X in `geom_point`, with x=ID and y=Ratio.

Secondly, I want to use the complete list of Values as a confidence interval, for the plotted values of X. In the end the plot should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please give us a reproducible example and show what you tried to do?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of 50% and 95% confidence intervals, using fake data:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Fake data
set.seed(295)
dat = data.frame(ID=rep(paste0("P",1:3),each=20), ratio=runif(60,0,1))

ggplot(dat, aes(ID, ratio)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", size=0.7, 
               width=0.03, colour="red") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, fun.args=list(conf.int=0.5), 
               geom="errorbar", size=5, width=0, color="lightblue") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", colour="red", pch="_", size=6) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]